# $g(x) = x^2f(x)$, how to prove $g'(x) = x^2 f'(x) + 2x f(x)$

Tags: derivatives

$g(x) = x^2f(x)$, how to prove $g'(x) = x^2 f'(x) + 2x f(x)$ without knowledge of the chain rule?

I have:

$g'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(a+h) - g(a)}{h}$
$= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(a+h)^2f(a) - a^2f(a+h)}{h}$

Is this correct? If so, whats the next step?

Comment: Or use product rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule

Comment: Hint: $g(x+h) = (x+h)^2 f(x+h) - (x+h)^2 f(x) + (x+h)^2 f(x)$

Comment: The Chain Rule is irrelevant. Did you mean without knowledge of the Product Rule?

Comment: @AndréNicolas one can prove the one from the other. So it doesn't really matter :D

Answer (score 3):

Your expression for $g'(x)$ is wrong (replace $a$ by $x$).

Expand that square and you should get your result.

Hint:$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {(x^2+2xh+h^2)f(x+h)-x^2f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {(2xh+h^2)f(x+h)+x^2(f(x+h)-f(x))}{h} =\lim \frac {something}{h}+x^2f'(x)$